# how do I get the dotted line segments in voronoi

Tags: scipy, voronoi

I am using scipy.spatial  to plot 2d Voronoi plots.

[image: example voronoi diagram]

In this example, the vertices for the three solid lines (from my `vor.vertices`) are:

[[ 0.51192507 -0.01397534]
[-0.02934272  0.47082063]
[ 0.49638053  0.61421268]]

I need the region boundaries around each point. The dotted lines have points outside the plane essentially at infinity, so the vertices off the plane are denoted with -1 in the ridge data, and are not represented in the vertices.

The data must be there somehow though, because the plt has a dotted line going off in some specific direction.

How can I extend the list of vertices or otherwise resolve data I am missing, such that I can recreate the regions around each point in terms of collections of discrete vertices?